# Is it possible to migrate valid LMA License records between LMA orgs?

Tags: managed-package, licenses, isv

Has anyone out there in the ISV/OEM ecosystem ever signed up customers in one LMA org, with official License records being created, and then, say, decided to spin-off this application into a separate company, and needed to set up a separate LMA org, and then wanted to transfer some of the Licenses from the original LMA org into the new LMA org?

As far as transferring the License records themselves, I know it's possible to export and import the records, but the LMA is weird --- I'm assuming that there is some sort of back-end linkage between the License records and Salesforce's License Management back-end that would be severed irrecoverably by doing this.

Has anyone tried this before, or have any insight into its feasibility based on their knowledge of how the LMA works on the back-end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just noticed this in the top-right paragraph of the AppExchange Publishing Console's License Management settings:

> You can only assign the LMO for a particular managed package ***once***.

So that seals the deal --- NO, it is not possible to migrate License Management records between LMO orgs.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I've been told by smart people on the salesforce partner team that no, this isn't possible. The data may move, but the link behind the scenes that enforces licensing doesn't seem to.

What you may want to consider, and I haven't tested this, is making a new major version of your app, linking the app against the new LMO, and then pushing a major upgrade. I'd expect this will generate new license records against the new LMO, and then you can turn off the old ones.

Comment: Ah, that seems like it would work, good idea! I will definitely try this once we have our new LMO org. I'll wait to see if anyone else has insight accepting this answer, though.